# Cannot boot Elementary OS Freya after installation on a former Windows netbook

Tags: boot, uefi, elementaryos

Asus X200MA, used to have Windows 8.1 preinstalled (with UEFI). I deleted all the partitions and installed elementary OS.

Now, without USB stick plugged in, the computer has no boot options (none for HDD) and goes straight into BIOS settings.
When I plug the live USB in, from the USB boot menu I can "boot from first hard disk", which gets me to the (initramfs) console.

How can I add the boot option for the hard drive? I don't know anything about UEFI and haven't seen an option to turn it off.
Is the (initramfs) a problem of some corrupted files or is it also something to do with this UEFI problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to

1. Update BIOS
2. Boot USB live stick in UEFI mode
3. Install eOS in UEFI mode (need 64bit)

Updating BIOS pretty much solved everything, it went just as you would expect afterwards.